# Deep linking launches the app, but handles the external url wrongly

Tags: react-native, deep-linking, react-navigation-v5, react-native-deep-linking

I am developing an React Native project, using React-Navigation v5.

I now try to implement deep linking feature. I followed the [official instruction](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/deep-linking/) set up deep linking successfully (I mean the app is launched by custom url scheme). Next I need to handle the external link, my issue comes at this point.

To handle external link in my react-native project, I also followed the instruction [configure links](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/configuring-links).

I defined a linking.js in my project:

```
const config = {
  screens: {
    // I explained why I nest FooScreen like this if you continue reading

    FeatureFlow: {
      SubfeatureFlow: {
        FooScreen: {
          path: 'foo/:myId',
        },
      },
    },
  },
};

const linking = {
  prefixes: ['myapp://mobile'],
  config,
};

export default linking;
```

Then, in my `NavigationContainer`, I use the linking as below:

```
return (
    <NavigationContainer
      linking={linking}
      ...
     >
      <MainFlow />
     </NavigationContainer>
```

As you can see above, three things worth a notice:

1. in linking.js, inside `config` I specified that the path e.g. `foo/123` should open screen `FooScreen`.
2. The `FooScreen` is a nested screen.
3. `NavigationContainer` contains a component called `MainFlow`.

To illustrated how `FooScreen` is nested in navigation hierarchy, let's start with `MainFlow`, which looks like this:

```
const MainFlow = ({navigation}) => {
  const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();
  return (
    <Drawer.Navigator
      ...>
      <Drawer.Screen name="FeatureFlow" component={MyFeatureFlow} />
      ...
    </Drawer.Navigator>
  );
};
```

As you can see, `MainFlow` is a `DrawerNavigator` which hosts a screen named `FeatureFlow` refers to component `MyFeatureFlow`.

And `MyFeatureFlow` looks like this:

```
const MyFeatureFlow = ({navigation}) => {
  const FeatureStack = createStackNavigator();

  return (
    <FeatureStack.Navigator
      ...>
       <FeatureStack.Screen
         name="SubfeatureFlow"
         component={MySubfeatureFlow}/>
    </FeatureStack.Navigator>
  )
```

As you can see above, `FeatureFlow` is a stack navigator which hosts a screen named `SubfeatureFlow`, refers to component `MySubfeatureFlow`.

And `MySubfeatureFlow` is like:

```
const MySubfeatureFlow = ({navigation}) => {
  const SubfeatureStack = createStackNavigator();

  return (
    <SubfeatureStack.Navigator
      ...>
       <SubfeatureStack.Screen
          name="FooScreen"
          component={MyFooScreen}
    </SubfeatureStack.Navigator>
  )
```

As you can see above, `MySubfeatureFlow` is another stack navigator which hosts a screen named `FooScreen` refers to component `MyFooScreen`.

Now you understand why in linking.js configuration, the `FooScreen` is nested like that.

Then, I run my app on iOS simulator. The app launched. I killed the app on simulator.

Then, I run command `npx uri-scheme open myapp://mobile/foo/123 --ios`. (I also tried open mobile browser, type in url `myapp://mobile/foo/123`, same error as below)

I see on simulator, the app is launched by the command, which means my deep linking is set up. However, handling external link to open `FooScreen` fails, I end up with the following error:

[image]

The error tells me the navigation payload tries to treat `123` as screen,  and the app treat `foo` as name of the screen in my project. I completely don't understand why it is. Is there something wrong with my linking configuration?

Comment: Are you using React Native CLI or Expo?